# Covariance matrix of Fourier amplitude spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, covariance

I want to compute a covariance matrix of Fourier amplitude spectrum. Paper said Matrix element is 
$A_{i,j} = \int_\Omega\langle x,e_i \rangle\langle x,e_j \rangle\,|l(x)|dx$

$l(x)$ is the Fourier spectrum. $e_i$ and $e_j$ are members of the canonical basis of the Fourier domain Ω. But What is a canonical basis?

I ask Paper author。He said:"In any vector space, the canonical basis are the vector with only one component equals to one and the others equals to zero. For example, in 3D:  e_0 = (1,0,0), e_1 = (0,1,0), e_2 = (0,0,1).

What that means is, in the context of 5D covariance tracing, where the space is (x,y,u,v,t):

\Sigma_0,0 is the variance for the x coordinate.
\Sigma_0,1 is the co-variance between the x and y coordinates.
\Sigma_0,2 is the co-variance between the x and u coordinate.

But expressed in the corresponding Fourier domain."
But in DFT ave negative frequency, inner product will be negative. I do not think canonical basis just ont component is one.

Comment: The canonical basis is exactly what the author told you. I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I have one problem when integral from negative frequency.When in results of Inner product depend on canonical basis, if only set  corresponding component to one. But DFT spectrum energy independ on frequency.I do nat understand just set component to one that is canonical basis.